# How to make grid lines thicker

Tags: jython, jes

Here is my code so far, my question is how do I make the white grid lines thicker and keep them 25 pixels apart? Please help

```
def grid():
  picture = makeEmptyPicture(365,365,black)
  w = getWidth(picture)
  h = getHeight(picture)
  vertical = 25
  horizontal = 25
  for y in range(0,h):
    for x in range(0,w):
      if (x % horizontal ==0 or y % vertical == 0):
      px = getPixel(picture,x,y)
      setColor(px, white)
  show(picture)
  return picture
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 0):

To make your lines bigger try drawing 2 lines at the same. For example

```
px1 = getPixel(picture, x, y+1)
px2 = getPixel(picture, x, y+1)
setColor(px1, white)
setColor(px2, white)
```

This will make the line bigger along the X-axis.

As for keeping the lines 25 pixels apart try incrementing your outer loop by 26 after every iteration.